# How can I await promise().done() with typescript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript, async-await

I know how to create a standard promise and use async/await to it but how can I await jquery promise().done() with typescript?

Current:

```
$('#sun').hide('slide', {direction:'right'}, 200).promise().done(function () {
    $('#rain').show('slide', {direction:'left'}, 200).promise().done(function () {
        console.log('ok!');
    });
});
```

I would like to do in this way but it does not work:

```
await $('#sun').hide('slide', {direction:'right'}, 200).promise().done(); 
await $('#rain').show('slide', {direction:'left'}, 200).promise().done();
console.log('ok!');
```

Comment: How does it not work, do you get any errors?

Comment: No, actually it works with javascript.
There is an error instead only with typescript:
`Error:(1569, 10) TS2555: Expected at least 1 arguments, but got 0.`
Anyway, removing done(), now it works.

Comment: Yeah, that's TypeScript complaining that you should not use `.done()` when you don't want to pass a callback function :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the `done()` call from the ends of your `promise()` calls. Without specifically looking into the jQuery promise implementation I would imagine calling `done()` without an argument returns `undefined` or an otherwise unawaitable result, so you're trying to `await undefined`.

Try awaiting the `promise()` call instead:

```
await $('#sun').hide('slide', {direction:'right'}, 200).promise(); 
await $('#rain').show('slide', {direction:'left'}, 200).promise();
console.log('ok!');
```

Comment: IIRC `.done()` returns the receiver object (the same promise again) so this should not be a problem, but still you're right that one should omit it.

Answer (score 0):

A [jquery promise](https://api.jquery.com/promise/) works in the same manner as a [vanilla promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

An example on how it works, convert this:

```js
var div = $( "<div>" );
 
div.promise().done(function( arg1 ) {
  // Will fire right away and alert "true"
  console.log( this === div && arg1 === div );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

to this:

```js
var div = $( "<div>" );

async function run(){
  const arg1 = await div.promise();
  console.log(arg1 === div );
}

window.onload = run;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**Solution:**

```
await $('#sun').hide('slide', {direction:'right'}, 200).promise(); 
await $('#rain').show('slide', {direction:'left'}, 200).promise();
console.log('ok!');
```